# How to capture process-space key events in OSX command-line tool, CoreFoundation, C API?

Tags: c, macos, core-foundation

I'm studying how to implement *key event* capturing and callback for a OSX no-GUI **command-line tool** within its process space, in **C**, using `CoreFoundation` only, (no `Cocoa`, no `NSEvents`). Upon some research, I could easily put together this *MCVE* on "global level" (which requires running the program with root privileges), but could not figure out what to do for capturing and processing key events in the program's *process space* only. I also haven't found documentation on how this can be done. I have found some questions from this area on SO, but all of them were `Cocoa` API based. I'll gladly provide any additional information needed.

```c
// gcc -Wall -o test test.c -framework ApplicationServices
// sudo test

#include <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>

CGEventRef testEventCallback(CGEventTapProxy proxy, 
                             CGEventType type, 
                             CGEventRef event, 
                             void *refcon)
{
    printf( " Event Type: %d\n", type );
    return event;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    CFMachPortRef       eventPort;
    CFRunLoopSourceRef  eventSrc;
    CFRunLoopRef        runLoop;
    CGEventMask mask = CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventKeyDown) | CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventKeyUp);
    eventPort = CGEventTapCreate(kCGSessionEventTap,
                                kCGHeadInsertEventTap,
                                kCGEventTapOptionListenOnly,
                                mask,
                                testEventCallback,
                                NULL );
    if ( eventPort == NULL ){
        printf( "NULL eventPort\n" );
        return 1;
    }

    eventSrc = CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource(NULL, eventPort, 0);
    if ( eventSrc == NULL ){
        printf( "NULL eventSrc\n" );
        return 1;
    }

    runLoop = CFRunLoopGetCurrent();
    if ( runLoop == NULL ){
        printf( "NULL runLoop\n" );
        return 1;
    }

    CFRunLoopAddSource(runLoop,  eventSrc, kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
    CFRunLoopRun();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "program's process space"?

Comment: Thanks for asking, @Willeke : I mean _"not system wide"_, but only for the particular program. I don't need to monitor key events user puts into other open programs, but only to this particular command line tool. Hope I'm a bit more clear now.

Comment: The documentation of `CGEventTapCreate` links to Event Tap Locations. At the bottom it says "In addition to the three tapping points described above, an event tap may also be placed where annotated events are delivered to a specific application. For more information, see the function CGEventTapCreateForPSN.".

Comment: This is very valuable info, @Willeke . I managed to modify the code getting PSN by calling `GetFrontProcess()`. Yet I don't understand why it still needs _superuser privileges_ to run `CGEventTapCreateForPSN` ? `sudo test`… I must be missing something very obvious.

Comment: A command-line tool never has keyboard focus as such. If you're running it from Terminal, then it's Terminal which has keyboard focus. There's no such thing as a key event in a command-line tool's process space.

Comment: Thanks for technical clarification @KenThomases. Your explanation is justified by the fact that `CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventKeyDown)`, i.e. masking key events, works for `GetFrontProcess()` called from within a command line tool, but not for `GetCurrentProcess()`. Yet, my question was if it is possible to `CGEventTapCreateForPSN` without requiring superuser runtime privileges?

Comment: "Event taps receive key up and key down events if one of the following conditions is true:
The current process is running as the root user.
Access for assistive devices is enabled."

Comment: @Willeke, thanks, I've read both [Quartz Event Service Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/) and [US Patent 20130239127](http://www.google.com/patents/US20130239127), where this was written. It is still unclear if this was so for globally tapping _Key Events_ where it is being mentioned (and is logical), or for _Key Events_ even strictly within a PSN (where it says nothing). So, you state what I'm looking for is _mission impossible_ without `sudo`ing or `UniversalAccess`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that works from a Swift command line tool running in Terminal. It taps the events that would normally be routed to Terminal.app, or whatever process was frontmost when the tool began running. It avoids consuming command keys so you can easily terminate the program with command-period if you need to. Since `GetFrontProcess()` is now deprecated, it uses `NSWorkspace` to locate the front process.

```
let lock = DispatchQueue(label: "lock")
var events = [CGEvent]()

// track keyboard events using an event tap.
let callback: CGEventTapCallBack =  { (tapProxy, eventType, event, _) -> Unmanaged<CGEvent>? in
  // don't consume command keys.
  if !event.flags.contains(.maskCommand) {
    if eventType == .keyDown {
      lock.sync {
        events.append(event)
      }
    }
    return nil
  }
  return Unmanaged<CGEvent>.passUnretained(event)
}

let eventMask = CGEventMask((1 << CGEventType.keyDown.rawValue) | (1 << CGEventType.keyUp.rawValue))
if let frontmostProcess = NSWorkspace.shared.frontmostApplication?.processIdentifier, let eventTap = CGEvent.tapCreateForPid(pid: frontmostProcess, place: .headInsertEventTap, options: .defaultTap, eventsOfInterest: eventMask, callback: callback, userInfo: nil) {
  let source = CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource(kCFAllocatorDefault, eventTap, 0)
  CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), source, .commonModes)
  CGEvent.tapEnable(tap: eventTap, enable: true)
  CFRunLoopRun()
}
```